# Overriding `this` in .bind and .apply

Tags: javascript

I was reading [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp) just to brush up on `.apply` syntax, and I realized I had a gap in my JS knowledge:

You can change the value of `this` in a function by using `.bind` and also `.apply` (I assume `.call` follows same rules as `.apply` so I'll not talk about that separately). So I wanted to know, if I use `.bind` and then call it with `.apply`, which will take precedence?

So I just yoinked the example from w3schools and modified it:

```js
var person = {
  fullName: function(city, country) {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "," + city + "," + country;
  }
}
var person1 = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
}

var person2 = {
  firstName: "Mary",
  lastName: "Anne"
}

fn = person.fullName.bind(person2);

console.log(fn.apply(person1, ["Oslo", "Norway"]));
```

So if it prints Mary Anne, the value of `this` given by `.bind` takes precedence over the value given by `.apply`.

And it did! Marry Anne was printed. So that leaves me wondering if there are any other rules regarding `this` that I don't quite understand. For example, can you rebind after calling `.bind`?

Comment: Seems pretty broad. But yes, `.call` and `.apply` are identical, except in how they handle the arguments after the *thisArg*.

Comment: I mean, how do we know what you do and don't understand? We could talk about arrow functions and calling with the `new` operator. But maybe you're already aware of those?

Comment: What is your question? You have asked 3 of them

Comment: Well... can you rebind an arrow function after declaring it? `fn = () => {}; fn = fn.bind(something)`; -- does that work?

Comment: These are all things you can test or likely find out from docs. Arrow functions have no `this` identifier in their variable environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bind` returns a *bound function*. *Bound functions* and *arrow functions* will never change their context again, so you can't re`.bind` them or `.apply` another context.

It might become more clear if we assume `.bind` would be written in JavaScript itself ... then it would be written as:

```
  function bind(context, ...args) {
    const fn = this;
    return function(...args2) {
      // Note: "this" does not get accessed inside this function, so .bind ing it or .apply ing another context doesnt change anything
      return fn.call(context, ...args, ...args2);
    }
 }
```

Comment: your helper function is good, but it also pre-binds the context, mine does not, which is what OP is looking for

Comment: @mrCholo not sure if he really needs that. This example was meant to illustrate the observable behaviour of .bind.

Comment: Many rational people including OP are looking for a way to pass the context later not earlier.  I know the solution b/c obviously I had the same question 2 years ago or whatever.

Comment: @MrCholo It's not about what many rational people use. OP asked for an explanation of the behaviour. Writing out what `bind` does in plain JavaScript might help this cause.

Comment: "most people use" I rarely use bind & apply at all

Comment: I use closures instead of bind/apply much more often. However bind is more generic, more performant, but less pretty and less explicit though. bind is also harder for type systems like TypeScript to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Per the specification:

> NOTE 2: If func is an arrow function or a **bound function** then the thisArg will be ignored by the function [[Call]] in step X.

This applies to all three binding functions.

`bind` creates a bound function which is not a normal function (it is an [exotic object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exotic-object)) and does not contain a prototype.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply

Comment: I don;t think call/apply create any functions, exotic or not.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing preventing a re-bind, except in the way that `Function.prototype.bind` is implemented. And you're right that once you call bind the `this` value is fixed and `Function.prototype.apply` can't override it.

Instead of using `Function.prototype.bind`, you can use this to bind arguments:

```
Function.prototype.create = function(){
  const args = arguments;
  const original = this;
  return function() {
    return original.call(this, ...args, ...arguments);
  }
};
```

however, modifying prototypes can be problematic, so I would avoid and create a helper function. I am sure utility libraries like lodash can do this, or ramda.

You can use it like this:

```
const fn = function (one, two, three) {
    return this + one + two + three;
};


const boundfn = fn.create(1, 2);
const val = boundfn.call(-6, 3);

console.log({val});
```

that's right, we passed `-6` as the value for `this`. :)

```
-6 + 6 = 0
```

**Note**: Avoid doing this! Playing with contexts is the wrong approach and definitely not functional. I would avoid passing `this` around because it's an invisible parameter and "harder to reason about".

Comment: Yes `Function.prototype.bind` is also currying, but it just pre-binds the `this` value, whereas this technique does not pre-bind `this`.

Answer (score 0):

`.bind` creates a new function with added `this` context and whatever arguments you want to *curry* and it is not possible to overwrite `this` with `apply`, `call` (unless your `bind` method is not native) there is an answer for that already https://stackoverflow.com/a/31656748/906265 which mentions [ES2015 spec for `bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.bind)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

`.apply` and `.call` allows you to override `this` value of a function at the time of calling it but will not work for arrow or bound functions as written in [ES2015 spec note 2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.call)

> If func is an arrow function or a bound function then the thisArg will be ignored by the function